# What is the reason for some people use GOTO statement in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have not experience in ObjectiveC (IOS) development but I've seen too many codes for curiosity and found some people using GOTO statement ([JsonKit Library](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit), some code games, etc), even the Apple's source code is known to use that ([You can see here](http://www.imore.com/understanding-apples-ssl-tls-bug)).

As I have learned in all my academic life, using GOTO is a very bad development pratice and must to be avoid, so why is it a "commom" pratice in IOS development, is there some special reason??

Comment: Common practice? I've been programming on iOS for 3.5 years and I've never seen it used except by newbies that are usually wondering if it's okay. I don't know what code you've been looking at but it's not common to me.

Comment: It's certainly not *common practice* in Objective-C. As a professional  iOS developer for nearly 6 years I've never once used a goto in any app, and I don't think I've ever come across other professional's code that does.

Comment: @daveMac beat me to the punch!

Comment: the reason is probably laziness, cause every problem can be solved in right way, but when you start to think in terms of shortcuts, suddenly your code starts to look like gibberish. I have proven many times that taking a little time to think about the solution always out ways time earned with shortcuts.

Comment: the SSL bug on iOS was due to a goto, so yes, apple developers use goto even if it isn't a common practice

Comment: I think that the curiosity of the use of GOTO in Obj-C has been sparked by the recent security bug found in iOS/OSX which was the result of a extra GOTO.  I agree that it is not common practice though.

Comment: The SSL code is not in Objective-C

Comment: In the JSONKit, they used plain C a lot, so this is really not related to Objective-C. `goto` is mostly used here and there for doing cleanups, becuse without objects, you have to `free()` the allocated memory.

Comment: People tell you that goto is very bad for development because if used by newbies the code gets really messy. So, only use goto if you really know what you are doing =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It is good programming style to use the `break`, `continue`, and
>   `return` statements instead of the `goto` statement whenever possible.
>   However, because the `break` statement exits from only one level of a
>   loop, you might have to use a `goto` statement to exit a deeply nested
>   loop.

*Source - [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b34dt9cd.aspx)

One more example from the [BLOG](http://blog.ablepear.com/2009/12/objective-c-tuesdays-common-uses-for.html)

Comment: What? Why you downvote?

Comment: So reason is mentioned above. It is used to exit from nested levels

Comment: This is not good, Objective-C also uses OOPS concept, and it also uses multilevel nesting

Comment: If you are not satisfied with that you can read at http://blog.ablepear.com/2009/12/objective-c-tuesdays-common-uses-for.html

Answer (score 0):

**MyExperience**

Academic is good and nice, but, in real, practical bad world, may happens that you have to exit from 2 or 3 nested for cycles under some conditions.

Yes, you could use three or two boolean variables, but why don't use the fast, old plain goto?

If you want, I can post a piece of code where I used goto.

```
for( int nITap = 0; nITap < m_nNumPercorsi; nITap++ )
{
    // .. blastuff
for( int nJTap = 0; nJTap < m_aPercorsi[nITap].m_nNumTappe - 1; nJTap++ )
    {
    // ..yet bla stuff
    for( nIndAd = 0; nIndAd < m_aNodi[nIndNodCor]->m_nNumNodiAd; nIndAd++ )
        if( m_aNodi[nIndNodSuc] == m_aNodi[nIndNodCor]->m_aNodiAdiacenti[nIndAd]->m_pNodoP2D )
            break;
    for( nICor = 0; nICor < m_aNodi[nIndNodCor]->m_aIndSeg.GetCount(); nICor++ )
    {
        for( nJCor = 0; nJCor < m_aNodi[nIndNodSuc]->m_aIndSeg.GetCount(); nJCor++ )
        {
           if( m_aNodi[nIndNodCor]->m_aIndSeg[nICor] == m_aNodi[nIndNodSuc]->m_aIndSeg[nJCor] )
           {
          nIndSpez = m_aNodi[nIndNodCor]->m_aIndSeg[nICor];
          goto L_SegmentoTrovato;
           }
        }
    }
L_SegmentoTrovato:
    aTmp.Add( nIndSpez );
```

Comment: Please do post an example where it's not "bad practice".

Comment: I've not said that is not a bad practice. Just easier.

Comment: Would like to know why a downvote, but I guess the same for @Himanshu 's one.

Comment: In many cases you can just nest another function call, and then use `return` in any nested loop. It's then sometimes called _readability_.

Comment: That's true and again right. In some cases btw, like this one, your code has to run VERY fast, so nesting too many function calls might be not a good idea. I'd probably post some more code to explain better but I can't.